# How can I connect a telegram bot to the free server?

Tags: python-2.7, server, python-telegram-bot

I'm built a telegram bot with Python-Telegram-Bot;But when the Python is closed, the telegram bot stops,So I want to connect it to the free server so it does not stop;But I do not know how to do it.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Fliters
import re


def delete_method(bot, update):
    if not update.message.text:
        print("it does not contain text")
        return

    mlist=['Hello', 'by']


    for i in mlist:
         if re.search(i, update.message.text):
             bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, message_id=update.message.message_id)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, delete_method))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# for exit
# updater.idle()
```

How can I connect a telegram bot to a free server?

Comment: What do you mean by 'free server'?

Comment: @TessellatingHecklerThis means a server that does not need money

Answer (score 1):

You could host your bot [here](https://www.heroku.com/python). That seems to be free. Also, take a look at [this page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Where-to-host-Telegram-Bots)

Comment: @EndogenI came to these pages but did not notice please explain more

Comment: @EndogenWhat should I do to make my robot always work ??

Comment: heroku is not free anymore